# Adding Carriage Returns without deleting numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,

Need a little help setting up a NotePad++ regex that will do the following. I have sentences preceded with outline level numbers that read all together as a single text string as shown belov:

1. Sentence bla bla  2. Sentence bla bla  3. Sentence bla bla  3a. Sentence bla bla  3b. Sentence bla bla  3c. Sentence bla bla

My goal is to get the data to look like it's shown below by adding new line carriage returns in front of the outline level numbers but at the same time I need the Regex to not care about the outline level numbers (i.e. 1. 2. 3. 3a. 3b. 3c.). I need the regex to leave these numbers alone and just insert new line carriage returns in front of these numbers so that the data looks like it is shown below:

1. Sentence bla bla
2. Sentence bla bla
3. Sentence bla bla

3a. Sentence bla bla

3b. Sentence bla bla

3c. Sentence bla bla

I have been experimenting with the following wild card characters:
.+?
Also:
\r\n

The problem is I can't get it to work.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Search:

```
(\b\d+[a-z]?\. )
```

Replace:

```
\r\n\1
```

Comment: Bohemian, thank you very much for your help.  I tried it out and it works nicely for all level one numbers.  However, for level two numbers such as 3.a.  3.b.  4.a.  4.b. the regex seems to skip them.  Can both levels be automatically changed using a single regex?

Comment: I tried adding this code [a z] to the regex (\b\d+\. ) for the purpose of targeting the second level outline numbers (i.e. 3.a. 3.b. 4.a. 4.b) but had no success. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Through Google I have learned the following:
\d A digit in the 0-9 range, same as [[:digit:]].
\a The BEL control character 0x07 (alarm). 
+ This matches 1 or more instances of the previous character, as many as it can.
However, it has not helped me figure out how to target the second level outline numbers such as 3.a. 3.b. 4.a. 4.b. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I deliberately left *out* the second levels because the sample output in your original question omitted them. I have edited the regex to *include* second levels.

Answer (score 0):

Find: \s([0-9].)

Replace: \n$1

then press "Replace All"